# Error: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

When I run the following code, in order to initializing a bidimensional matrix:

```
X_train_word2vec = np.array(X_train_word2vec)
train_x = np.zeros([X_train_word2vec.shape[0], 150])

for i, sentence in enumerate(X_train_word2vec):
    for j, word in enumerate(sentence):
        train_x[i,j] = model_word2vec.wv[word]
```

Where `X_train_word2vec` has shape `(12481,)`, and `train_x` has shape `(12481, 150)`. I get this error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Why? I suppose that there is something wrong about the shape of the arrays, but I'm not sure.

**Update:**
The traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bbd0ab46f676> in <module>()
      4 for i, sentence in enumerate(X_train_word2vec):
      5     for j, word in enumerate(sentence):
----> 6         train_x[i,j] = model_word2vec.wv[word]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**Update 2:**

I have found that the problem regards the assignment of an array as an element of   `train_x` matrix, because it seems that we can assign only `int` or `float` as elements of a matrix.

Comment: Presumably the error occurs at the line `train_x[i,j] = model_word2vec.wv[parola]`.  If you included the *compete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message), we wouldn't have to guess where the error occurs.  Check the value of `model_word2vec.wv[parola]`; is it what you expect?  What is its type?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have added the traceback. `model_word2vec.wv[word]` is a `Gensim Word2Vec` array, which length is `150`. I would like to get the `Word2Vec` array for each word in the set of sentences in `X_train_word2vec`.